# Open Macvim within terminal without opening a new window

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, macvim

Every time I try to edit a file, I do `mvim file.txt` in the terminal then a new MacVim window pops up. But if I do `vim file.txt`, it will not open a new window. Instead, it will initialise vim within the terminal.

**Question:** How can I make sure that when I do `mvim file.txt`, MacVim will be opened up within the terminal just like what I did using `vim`.

I have tried the following solution already but it doesn't work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478755/macvim-open-file-in-existing-window

Answer (score 5):

```
$ mvim -v file.txt
```

does what you want.

You should alias `vim` to `mvim -v`, IMO.

Comment: I tried `alias vim = "mvim -v"` but couldn't manage to source the .bash_profile. Did I do something wrong. I got these 2 errors msg: `-bash: alias: vim: not found`
`-bash: alias: =mvim -v: not found`

Comment: Try `alias vim='/path/to/mvim -v'`.

Comment: Spaces can't go around the `=` in the `alias` command.